# Stack overflow in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, stack-overflow

Yesterday I came across an error which I was puzzled by and had a little laugh at.

I opened my website in Internet explorer (I use chrome 99% of the time)
and  got a "Stack Overflow" error.

I was just wondering is this a bad thing because when I open it in chrome or firefox it loads fine. Also does this happen to anyone else?

the website is, [www.illstudylater.com](http://www.illstudylater.com)

Comment: How is browser incompatibilities related to PHP? What version of IE? This is probably badly built site.

Comment: i thougth stack overflow issue was related to a sluggy php script

Comment: The fact that it only occurs in Internet explorer suggests that it's javascript.

Comment: It works on IE8. What browser are you using?

Comment: IE8 aswell, though now that some one mentions a java issue. i have been having problems with my java scripts lately.

sorry for the lack of knowledge  guys, i've just started in the whole website industry.

Comment: Java and Javascript are two different things. Javascript is handled by the browser.

Comment: It won't open in Safari on my iPhone as well, so you've got some problems.

Answer (score 2):

It's only bad if any of your users will be using Internet Explorer.  So yes.

Comment: any suggestions on how one would fix it?
from what i read it basicaly means the scripts too heavy

Comment: It means that you have runaway recursion with no base case.  Nothing to do with "heaviness".  In all your recursive functions, make sure you have a base case that will be reached in a reasonable amount of call depth.

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

> In software, a stack overflow occurs
>   when too much memory is used on the
>   call stack. The call stack contains a
>   limited amount of memory, often
>   determined at the start of the
>   program. The size of the call stack
>   depends on many factors, including the
>   programming language, machine
>   architecture, multi-threading, and
>   amount of available memory. When too
>   much memory is used on the call stack
>   the stack is said to overflow,
>   typically resulting in a program
>   crash. This class of software bug is
>   usually caused by one of two types of
>   programming errors.
>
> - Infinite recursion
> - Very large stack variables

When this error is thrown, recursion is the more popular reason.

I've tried the site in IE8 without problems, so perhaps it is an old version of IE causing a problem.

Comment: yea, what i got from that and from what i asked someone at my uni, i got the idea that it basically ment your php script was shit and slow. 

So long as its working on other peoples im fine with that. i'll try reinstalling IE8 and java and hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: Recursion is more common, but if the bug is browser dependent then it seems more likely that an IE memory leak caused by your handling of stack variables in PHP.  Perhaps the memory leak was later fixed in IE8?